# Convergence of series over arbitary set

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, several-complex-variables

Can any one explain to me,what is meant by convergence of a series defined over an arbitary indexing set?

Context:I was checking definition of holomorphic map of several variables where the power series is defined without mention of any absolute convergence(so rearrangement theorem is not applicable).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide either an exact quote or else a link or reference to where you came across the scenario you described.

Answer (score 1):

If $(a_i)_{i \in \mathcal I}$ is an indexed set of real numbers, split $\mathcal I$ into two parts:
$$ \mathcal I_+ = \{i : a_i \ge 0\}, \quad
\mathcal I_- = \{i : a_i < 0\} .$$
Then define
$$ S_+ = \sup\left\{\sum_{a \in \mathcal J} a_i : \text{$\mathcal J$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal I_+$} \right\} ,$$
$$ S_- = \sup\left\{-\sum_{a \in \mathcal J} a_i : \text{$\mathcal J$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal I_-$} \right\} .$$
Then
$$ \sum_{i \in \mathcal I} a_i = S_+ - S_- .$$
Note if both $S_+$ and $S_-$ are infinite, then the sum is undefined.  So the sum is only defined and finite if the indexed set is absolutely summable.